# How to import and use SVG File in my App.js view

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to import this in my react native project's Appjs view.
I tried many ways but its not working. I mean i want to render it inside My view. How can I import and show this file in my Appjs?

Here is my code:

```
import ForwardRef from '../../constants/UI_login/Home_Landing_Page/BackgroundComponent'
import React from "react";
import Svg, { Defs, LinearGradient, Stop, Rect } from "react-native-svg";
/* Adobe XD React Exporter has dropped some elements not supported by react-native-svg: style */

const BackgroundComponent = ({ svgRef }) => (
  <Svg width={375} height={247} viewBox="0 0 375 247" ref={svgRef}>
    <Defs>
      <LinearGradient
        id="a"
        x1={0.5}
        y1={0.807}
        x2={0.5}
        y2={1}
        gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      >
        <Stop offset={0} stopColor="#fff" />
        <Stop offset={1} stopColor="#fff" stopOpacity={0} />
      </LinearGradient>
    </Defs>
    <Rect className="a" width={375} height={247} />
  </Svg>
);

const ForwardRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <BackgroundComponent svgRef={ref} {...props} />
));
export default ForwardRef;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
//import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Routes from './components/Routes';
import {firebaseConfig} from "./constants/ApiKeys";


import {AppContainer} from './components/Navigation'

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

if (!firebase.apps.length) { firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); }

console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Setting a timer'];
export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (

      <AppContainer/>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this project built? Are you using webpack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import and use this File in my App.js view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502634/how-to-import-and-use-this-file-in-my-app-js-view)